# Will a AWD EV have less range than a RWD EV?

Tags: electric-vehicles

A RWD<sup>1</sup> ICE<sup>2</sup> car has more range/mpg than the same version of the car with AWD<sup>3</sup>.

Is this true for electric vehicles as well ?

For example we have a RWD electric car called Z with 300 miles of range. How much range will the same car have if it is made AWD by adding a motor to the front ?

Is the difference significant or negligible ? Or is there a difference at all ?

---

<sup>1</sup> Rear-wheel drive.
<sup>2</sup> Internal combustion engine.
<sup>3</sup> All wheel drive.
EV = electric vehicle.

Comment: I would recommend you start by reading info on exactly **how** AWD BEVs work.  Teslas, for example, only use one motor except in hard acceleration and low-traction situations.  There are upcoming vehicles (from other companies) which put one motor on each wheel, using a lot of software to coordinate distribution of power.

Answer (score 1):

Like Carl Witthoff explain this is not very straight forward.

### ICE

Generally in ICE because there is a single engine, AWD consistently have less mpg compared to RWD. E.g.

|  | mpg city | highway | source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 Dodge Challenger RWD | 19 | 30 | [fueleconomy](https://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/noframes/42323.shtml) |
| 2020 Dodge Challenger AWD | 18 | 27 | [fueleconomy](https://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/noframes/42328.shtml) |

The difference is about 5-10% depending on usage. This is attributed to the losses on the more complex gear trains.

### Electric vehicle drivetrains

Depending on the type of vehicle fully electric / hybrid there are several configurations that are possible for a AWD drive (and similar to a RWD).

The following picture shows different configurations for hybrid and BEV vehicles.

[image]

**Figure : : Different front wheel drive EV configurations (source [A Comprehensive Study of Key Electric Vehicle (EV)
Components, Technologies, Challenges, Impacts, and
Future Direction of Development](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.preprints.org%2Fmanuscript%2F201705.0090%2Fv1%2Fdownload&psig=AOvVaw2HGB1C-zz39V4tM-TYJD7o&ust=1631102106495000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0Q3YkBahcKEwj43JKA5-zyAhUAAAAAHQAAAAAQDg))**

On the bottom are the BEV. As you can see there is a lack of gear boxes, which in turn minimizes the losses.

However conceivably (a lot of things indicate towards that direction), there can be a transition stage where the following configuration is possible:

- batteries on the floor or on the structure of the car
- a front/central electric motor will substitute the ICE,
- a geartrain from the Electric motor to the RWD (or AWD), using conventional differential arrangements.

In the last scenario, I would expect that the fuel economy of the RWD and the AWD are comparable.